# Vertically align buttons in table with varying text size above (using bootstrap grid)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

Although this question seems to be a common problem, I could not find any discussion on SO with a similar problem. I am trying to vertically align buttons in a pricing table. The problem is changing text size above, when making the browser narrow, which results in pushing the buttons downwards unequally.

This website (https://joinhomebase.com/homebase-pricing/) shows 4 buttons that move down, as soon as you make the browser narrower, and they stay always vertically aligned. At the same time the text above wraps to 3 or 4 lines. That is exactly what I want to achieve, but by analysing the developer tools information I could not find out which CSS parameter is relevant.

I am using Bootstrap Grid with only 1 row, so that the columns get stacked above each other, when the screen is very narrow. I am using ReactJS as well, but that is IMO not relevant for this question. [image: This image shows that in the middle column the button is pushed down.]

```css
#pricing-table {
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
}

#pricing-header {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0 40px;
  background-color: #64B1BC;
  padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35pt;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: Raleway, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.pricing-col-title {
  color: black;
  font-size: 18pt;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #021a40;
}

.pricing-col {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 1em;
  border-left: 1px solid #021a40;
  border-top: 1px solid #021a40;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #021a40;
  text-align: center;
}

.pricing-row {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #021a40;
}

.pricing-col-adtext-container {
  min-height: 90px; //does not work when making browser narrower
  //height: 90px;     //creates overlapping text
}

.pricing-col-adtext {
  color: black;
  font-size: 14pt;
  padding: 0.5em;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: Raleway, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.pricing-col-price {
  color: black;
  font-size: 18pt;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Raleway, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.pricing-btn-signup-container {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.pricing-btn-signup {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 0.5em;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f9b200;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Raleway, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.pricing-col-feature {
  color: black;
  font-size: 14pt;
  padding: 1em 1em 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: Raleway, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="pricing-table" className="container">
  <div>
    <h1 id="pricing-header">Pick the plan that's best for you. </h1>
  </div>


  <div className="row pricing-row">

    <div className="col-md-4 pricing-col">
      <h3 className="pricing-col-title">Free</h3>
      <div className="pricing-col-adtext-container">
        <h4 className="pricing-col-adtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>
      </div>
      <h2 className="pricing-col-price">Free</h2>
      <div className="pricing-btn-signup-container">
        <a role="button" className="btn btn-primary btn-lg pricing-btn-signup" href="">Sign up</a>
      </div>
      <ul className="pricing-col-feature">
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
      </ul>

    </div>


    <div className="col-md-4 pricing-col">
      <h3 className="pricing-col-title">Standard</h3>
      <div className="pricing-col-adtext-container">
        <h4 className="pricing-col-adtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et.</h4>
      </div>
      <h2 className="pricing-col-price">Free</h2>
      <div className="pricing-btn-signup-container">
        <a role="button" className="btn btn-primary btn-lg pricing-btn-signup" href="">Sign up</a>
      </div>

      <ul className="pricing-col-feature">
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
      </ul>

    </div>

    <div className="col-md-4 pricing-col">
      <h3 className="pricing-col-title">Premium</h3>
      <div className="pricing-col-adtext-container">
        <h4 className="pricing-col-adtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.</h4>
      </div>
      <h2 className="pricing-col-price">Free</h2>
      <div className="pricing-btn-signup-container">
        <a role="button" className="btn btn-primary btn-lg pricing-btn-signup" href="">Sign up</a>
      </div>

      <ul className="pricing-col-feature">
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>


  <div className="container-fluid footer">
    <Footer/>
  </div>

</div>
```

Besides the described problem, my code has probably weeknesses - any hints welcome, I am a frontend beginner.

Edit: I am building upon a stylesheet of bootswatch (link removed from this text for unknown reasons)

Comment: The website you reference uses statically defined `height`s, perhaps that is an option. You may also want to take a look at (the fairly new) CSS grid.

Comment: In my understanding, your reference site plays with the 'height' of the div(just above the button) using some script. In a desktop version it is having a 'height:32px' as an inline style. when you resize, as soon as the text breaks into 3 lines, the inline height changes to 48px. So it is not a pure css solution.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.row.is-flex{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row.is-flex > [class*='col-'] {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

/*
* And with max cross-browser enabled.
* Nobody should ever write this by hand.
* Use a preprocesser with autoprefixing.
*/
.row.is-flex {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row.is-flex > [class*='col-'] {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row is-flex">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="col-12" style="background: red;">
        <h1>test1</h1>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto ut quae, blanditiis aut sapiente cum recusandae, quasi consequatur quia sint ab debitis similique, nisi temporibus minus maxime distinctio error iure.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-12" style="background: orange;">
        <h1>test2</h1>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto ut quae, blanditiis aut sapiente cum recusandae, quasi consequatur quia sint ab debitis similique, nisi temporibus minus maxime distinctio error iure.
      recusandae, quasi consequatur quia sint ab debitis similique, nisi temporibus minus maxime distinctio error iure.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="col-12" style="background: blue;">
        <h1>test3</h1>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto ut quae, blanditiis aut sapiente cum recusandae, quasi consequatur quia sint ab debitis similique, nisi temporibus minus maxime distinctio error iure.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Apove here is that all divs are allways the same height 
[codepen](https://codepen.io/justmemaarten/pen/xeQmmb)

Below i writed a new code for you - the button will always stay on bottom.

```css
.outer .inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;            /*  stack items vertically  */
}
.outer .inner .button {
  margin-top: auto;                  /*  push button to bottom  */
}


/* styling for this demo only  */
.outer {
  display: flex;
}
.outer .inner {
  width: 33.333%;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
.outer .inner .header,
.outer .inner .text {
  padding: 10px;
}
.outer .inner .button {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="text">Some text</div>
    <div class="button">Button</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam, nobis consequatur illum rem dicta laborum aliquam enim mollitia minima cum accusantium porro provident, nam recusandae tempore in? Dolore, fugit nemo.</div>
    <div class="button">Button</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="text">Some text that is middle middle middle middle long</div>
    <div class="button">Button</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[here the new codepen (button always on bottom](https://codepen.io/justmemaarten/pen/JVeVdz)

Comment: I tested your code, but could not see any impact. Your codepen does not have buttons below the text, maybe you could extend to demonstrate?

Comment: Thanks. I see your code is running fine in the codepen, however, I couldn't get it to run for me. Since I intend to have the columns stacked over each other for narrow screens (which is already working) I use bootstrap grid, which is not used in your example.

Comment: @GregHolst you can use the classes of bootstrap but dont forget to add the css to it i made it should work